# Pandas index labelling type error within multiprocessing code

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I've been wrestling with getting the below multiprocessing code to work (to append nearest stores to a customer file using co-ordinates).

I believe it's a pandas issue that's causing the problem, potentially something to do with passing the dataframe into the function parallelize_dataframe() where it's splits into different numpy arrays (that's just a guess). Oddly, when I run on the full postcodes file (rather than the test customer file), it doesn't crash (ran for 15 mins until I stopped it), however, as postcodes is 2.6m records long, I don't know if it just hadn't reached the point where it would crash, or if I'm introducing the problem when I create the test files.

It's a long process that utilises most of my CPU, so I want to prove it works on the the test files first before letting it run for a long time on the full file.

Either way, it persistently throws an index labelling type error (at end of post).

Any help with this appreciated.

```
import multiprocess as mp #pip install multiprocess
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import functools

postcodes = pd.read_csv('national_postcode_stats_file.csv')

customers = postcodes.sample(n = 10000, random_state=1) # customers test file
stores = postcodes.sample(n = 100, random_state=1) # store test file
stores.reset_index(inplace=True)

cores = mp.cpu_count() # 8 CPUs
partitions = cores

def parallelize_dataframe(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
    pool = mp.Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def dist_func(stores, data):

    # Reimport libraries (parellel processes completed in fresh interpretter each time)

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np 

    def nearest(inlat1, inlon1, inlat2, inlon2, store, postcode):
        lat1 = np.radians(inlat1)
        lat2 = np.radians(inlat2)
        longdif = np.radians(inlon2 - inlon1)
        r = 6371.1009 # gives d in kilometers
        d = np.arccos(np.sin(lat1)*np.sin(lat2) + np.cos(lat1)*np.cos(lat2) * np.cos(longdif)) * r
        near = pd.DataFrame({'store': store, 'postcode': postcode, 'distance': d})
        near_min = near.loc[near['distance'].idxmin()]
        x = str(near_min['store']) + '~' + str(near_min['postcode']) + '~' + str(near_min['distance'])
        return x

    data['appended'] = data['lat'].apply(nearest, args=(data['long'], stores['lat'], stores['long'], stores['index'], stores['pcds']))
    data[['store','store_postcode','distance_km']] = data['appended'].str.split("~",expand=True)
    return data

dist_func_with_stores = functools.partial(dist_func, stores) # Needed to pass stores to parrellize_dataframe

dist = parallelize_dataframe(customers, dist_func_with_stores)
```

And the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-34-7a1b788055e2>", line 41, in dist_func
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3591, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2217, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3578, in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwds)
  File "<ipython-input-34-7a1b788055e2>", line 37, in nearest
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1500, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1912, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_key(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1799, in _validate_key
    self._convert_scalar_indexer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 262, in _convert_scalar_indexer
    return ax._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=self.name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py", line 211, in _convert_scalar_indexer
    ._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=kind))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2877, in _convert_scalar_indexer
    return self._invalid_indexer('label', key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3067, in _invalid_indexer
    kind=type(key)))
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-7a1b788055e2> in <module>
     45 dist_func_with_stores = functools.partial(dist_func, stores) # Needed to pass stores to parrellise_dataframe
     46 
---> 47 dist = parallelize_dataframe(customers, dist_func_with_stores)

<ipython-input-34-7a1b788055e2> in parallelize_dataframe(data, func)
     16     data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
     17     pool = mp.Pool(cores)
---> 18     data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
     19     pool.close()
     20     pool.join()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269 
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Look into module scipy.spacial.distance for distance calculations, in particular [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist), looks like that can solve the problem you're trying to solve in a much faster way (might not need parallelizing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - changed the apply to a lambda function - works fine now.

```
data['appended'] = data.apply(lambda row: nearest(row['lat'], row['long'], stores['lat'], stores['long'], stores['index'], stores['pcds']),axis=1)
```